# ¿Cómo hago para imprimir varias veces el mismo texto dentro de un componente html?

Tags: javascript

Necesito resolver que en la celda Numero 1 me imprima "mi nombre" tantas veces lo indique el numero que el usuario coloque en la celda Numero 1(del 1 al 10)

```js
function nombre() {
  var var1=document.querySelector("#idPrimero").value;
  var num1 = Number(var1);
  var leyenda= document.querySelector("#lblResultado");
  var i= num1;
  for (i=0; i<=num1; i++){
    leyenda.innerHTML= "El resultado es:" mi nombre + i;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="caja">
  <label for="">Numero 1:</label> 
  <input type="text" name="txtNum1" id="idPrimero" class="clasePrimero">          
  <label for="">Numero 2:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtNum2" id="idSegundo" class= "claseSegundo">  
  <p id="lblResultado"></p>
<div/>
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar en tu código no haces el llamado a la función `nombre`, tampoco pones la función `Number()`, que creo debería ser `parseInt()` para convertir a entero. Por ultimo si solo colocas el `innerHTML` el contenido se reemplazará.

Para esto he creado una etiqueta `<div>` donde se guardará cada resultado de la iteración el cual será una etiqueta `<p>` y en vez de hacer una asignación (`=`), hacemos una concatenación (`+=`). También cree un botón para poder ejecutar la función correspondiente

```js
btn = document.getElementById("ejecutar")
btn.addEventListener("click",nombre)

function nombre() {
  let veces =document.querySelector("#idPrimero").value;
  let leyenda = document.querySelector("#lblResultado");
  veces = parseInt(veces);
  
  for (i=0; i<=veces; i++){
    leyenda.innerHTML += `<p>El resultado es: mi nombre ${i}</p>`
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="caja">
  <label for="">Numero 1:</label> 
  <input type="text" name="txtNum1" id="idPrimero" class="clasePrimero">          
  <label for="">Numero 2:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtNum2" id="idSegundo" class= "claseSegundo"> 
  <button id="ejecutar">Ejecutar</button>
  <div id="lblResultado"></div>
<div/>
```

En caso no quieras que aparezca el `0` solo cambia la variable `i=0` por `i=1` esto hará que la variable inicie en 1, luego también puedes añadir una validación para saber si el número se encuentra entre el 1 y el 10.

Comment: no me funciona con `<p>El resultado es: mi nombre ${i}</p>`

Comment: Mm...Que te sale?

Comment: Number() es una función definida del lenguaje al igual que parseInt.

Comment: Haaa bueno, @FacundoE.Villagra hace tiempo no trabajo con JS,  pero de igual forma funciona

Answer (score 0):

Aca te dejo una version resumida de tu consulta, en este caso imprimo directamente la frase con el nombre ingresado en el input 1, la cantidad de veces que se ingresa en el input 2, podes modificarlo para que haga exactamente lo que buscabas.

```js
function nombre() {
document.getElementById("lblResultado").innerHTML = Array.from({length:parseInt(document.querySelector("#cantidad").value)})
  .map(x=>document.querySelector("#nombre").value)
  .map((item,i) =>"<p>El resultado es:" + item +" - "+i+"</p>")
  .join("</br>")
}
```

```html
<div id="caja">
  <label for="">Nombre:</label> 
  <input type="text" name="txtNum1" id="nombre" class="clasePrimero">          
  <label for="">Cantidad:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtNum2" id="cantidad" class= "claseSegundo">  
  <button onclick="nombre()">Ejectuar </button>
  <div id="lblResultado"> </div>
<div/>
```